# Markov process in continuous time: meaning of derivative wrt time

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose we have a Markov process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$, taking values on $\mathcal{N}$, with this Q-matrix (Example 17.27 of Probability Theory, 3rd version, by A. Klenke):
$$
q(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
x &\text{if } y=x+1\\ 
-x &\text{if } y=x\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Let $f_n(t):=P_1[X_t>n]$. **How can I obtain in a formal way and give a meaning to this?**

$$
\frac{d}{dt}f_n(t)=nP_1[X_t=n]
$$

I know that $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n\in \mathcal{N}$ and that $X$ jumps from $n$ to $n+1$ at rate $n$. This is what the author is saying to obtain the expression but it is not enough for me to see what he's doing.

Thanks for the help. Let me know if more context is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it looks like the CTMC never decreases. You fix $\delta>0$ with $\delta \approx 0$ and use the Law of Total Probability:  \begin{align}
P[X(t+\delta)>n]
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[X(t+\delta)>n|X(t)=i]P[X(t)=i]\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} P[X(t+\delta)>n|X(t)=i]P[X(t)=i]+P[X(t)>n]\end{align}
where we have used the nondecreasing property of $X(t)$ to obtain  $$P[X(t+\delta)>n|X(t)=i]=1 \quad \forall i>n$$

Then:

- $P[X(t+\delta)>n|X(t)=n]=n\delta+O(\delta^2)$
- $P[X(t+\delta)>n|X(t)=i]=O(\delta^2) \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., n-1\}$

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee of $O(\delta^2)$, just $o(\delta)$.

Comment: @Ian Here I am using that if $Y\sim Exp(n)$ then $P[Y> \delta] = e^{-n\delta} = 1-n\delta + O(\delta^2)$. So $$P[X(t+\delta)>n|X(t)=n]=P[Y\leq \delta]=n\delta + O(\delta^2)$$

Comment: Ah, right, these are bona fide exponentials.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the very clear answer, I didn't think about it at all. One question: how do you understand that there are exponentials involved from, basically, only the given the Q-matrix?

Comment: This comes from the definition of a CTMC: In state $i$, there are outgoing rates $q_{ij}$ and these compete as independent racing exponentials $X_{ij}$, whichever exponential "wins" (comes first) is the place we transition to, at that time. Your case is particularly simple since there is only one outgoing link per state so we know where we go next: Given we are in state $n$, there is only one exponential $X_{n,n+1}$ in the race, it always wins, so we transition to state $n+1$ after that "winning" time $X_{n,n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you @Michael. Could you point me a reference where it is written the fact about the relationship between a CTMC and the independent racing exponentials? I do not think is clearly expressed in the book I cited.

Comment: Well, that is the way I teach it: There are two equivalent views of the dynamics of a CTMC: (i) The racing exponential game; (ii) The amount of time spent in each state $i$ is $Exp(v_i)$ (where $v_i$ is the sum of outgoing rates) and at time of transition we independently choose a new state $j$ with prob $P_{ij} = q_{ij}/v_i$. The second description is in *Introduction to Probability Models* by Sheldon Ross. That book will also show why independent racing exponentials is equivalent to a single exponential with the sum rate (though it may not call it the "racing exponential game" as I do).

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I will find a copy of your suggested reference to better understand what is going on. In the meantime I’m trying to see if I am able to see the link between the “racing exponentials” and the book I am studying: very hard!